# Why doesn't this $_GET work

Tags: php, html

I am just trying to get the values from a table, but for some reason GET isn't working for me, or I am doing something wrong. Here is how I create my table in one php file:

```
    <?php
    .
    .
        .
        .
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Login ID</td>";  
        $j=1;
        echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";  
        $j=2;
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Password</td>";
    $j=3;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Birthday</td>";
    $j=4;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Address</td>";
    $j=5;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Email</td>";
    $j=6;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Phone Number</td>";
    $j=7;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$line[$j]' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

The names should be the number 1-7 right?

In another php file I attempt to access the values in those fields with he following code:

```
    <?php
.
.
.
.
$login_id = $_GET['1'];
$name = $_GET['2'];
$pw = $_GET['3'];
$bday = $_GET['4'];
$address = $_GET['5'];
$email = $_GET['6'];
$phno = $_GET['7'];


echo "new: $login_id, $name, $pw, $bday, $address, $email, $phno";

?>
```

Here is what I end up getting back: `new: , , , , , ,`

So what is it that I am doing wrong? I can't seem to find anything wrong with my code. I know I should probably be using $_POST for the password.

Comment: where is ur <form> tag in 1st page??

Comment: which method you are using to post your data.

Comment: I don't think GET variables can be numbers, or start with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not put the `<form>` tag. Add tag in begining

```
<form action='another_page.php' method='get'>
```

and in the end write

```
<input type='submit' name='submit>
</form>
```

What it will do on submit it will forward the values to the another page.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I had it at the bottom before, I had no idea it made a difference!

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    echo "<form action='otherfile.php' method='get'><tr>";
    echo "<td>Login ID</td>";  
        $j=1;
        echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";  
        $j=2;
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Password</td>";
    $j=3;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Birthday</td>";
    $j=4;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Address</td>";
    $j=5;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Email</td>";
    $j=6;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Phone Number</td>";
    $j=7;  
    echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value='$j' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Submit Data</td>";
    echo "<td><input name='submitdata' type='submit' value='submit' size=20/></td>";
    echo "</tr><form>";
?>
```

if you want submit then get the all value in otherfile.php file

try its working...

Answer (score 1):

```
       <form name="login" method="get" action="youraction.php">
        echo "<td><input name=$j type='text' value=$j /></td>";
       </form>

   youraction.php
   ---------------

         <?php
          if($_GET)
            {
             print_r($_GET);
            }
          ?>
```